# Credit card number in credit report. Acceptable or not?

Tags: privacy, credit-card

I recently applied to obtain my credit report for the very first time and was taken by surprise when I saw all my credit card numbers mentioned in the report without any masking. I had seen other credit reports in the past (issued by different agencies) which mentioned credit card details without providing the actual card number. Is this an acceptable practice? I am not able to understand the purpose of providing unmasked credit card numbers in the report. Isn't it supposed to contain only metadata which allows lenders to assess my creditworthiness.

A bit of background:

I applied for this credit report online using a third party marketplace which used the services of the rating agency in question. The credit report was immediately made available over email. I am a resident of India and the rating agency in question is a well known global player. The report contained details on all three of my currently held credit cards, all of which are from different service providers.

Comment: I don't think it's acceptable, however given that the credit provider itself isn't bound by PCI I doubt they'll get anything even if the card networks look into it. Whoever sent them the card number during the credit check might be in some trouble though, if 1) you could find out who they were and 2) get the card networks to look into it. Also, which country is this?

Comment: In Germany you can get a credit report (self-disclosure). All information, such as credit card numbers, etc. are in plain text. This is also important, because invalid information affect your score.

Comment: @AndréBorie This is India and the report contained CC information for cards issued from three different financial institutions. I wonder how come everybody is sending card numbers in plain.